# How do you give an "alert = prompt" a variable?

Tags: javascript, prompt

As the title says, I have a couple of "alert = prompt" and I need to make the prompt part a variable so I can read it back to the customer.

Any ideas?

```
 alert = prompt("Please enter your phone number:")
 alert = prompt("Please enter your delivery address:")
```

Comment: what are you talking about? Can you give us some codes?

Comment: try this: look at your question as if you do not anything about the problem you are trying to solve. Then ask yourself whether you understand what is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be more specific, but I think what your getting at is something like this?

`var alert = prompt("Something in here");`

But to  get the best answers, be more specific and give some sample code (even if it doesn't work, it helps a lot)

Comment: just added what I have so far

Comment: but essentially yes, that is what I was looking for with the "var alert = prompt" how to you change them so they each have their own name. (does it go like this: "var alertphonenumber = prompt(..."  )

Comment: then yes, you do this: `var input1 = prompt("Please enter your phone number:"); var input2 = prompt("Please enter your delivery address:"); var returnBack = "You entered " + input1 + " and " + input2);`